# Ovewrite gallery.phtml file in Magento2 from custom module

Tags: xml, magento, templates, overriding, magento2

Hi I am building a module in which I need to override a `gallery.phtml` file from my module file.

For this I have create a catalog_product_view.xml in our module layout folder with following content

```
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">

    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.media.image" remove="true"/>
        <referenceContainer name="product.info.media">

                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Gallery" name="product.info.media.image" template="product/view/gallery.phtml"/>

        </referenceContainer>

    </body>
</page>
```

but it is not rendering a file from here. When I set
`<referenceBlock name="product.info.media.image" remove="true"/>`  to false it starts rendering a base image.

Please suggest what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 2):

ok i got it and fixed below

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>

        <referenceBlock name="product.info.media.image" remove="true"/>

        <referenceContainer name="product.info.media">
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Gallery" name="product.info.media.cusimage" template="Eecom_Productzoom::Eecom_Productzoom/gallery.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

In this i have create a file here Eecom_Productzoom/gallery.phtml and now it works .